# XStream doesn't show CData tags

Tags: java, xml, xstream

When I read an XML with XStream, it doesn't show  tag `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`.
I'd like XStream to show it.

For example:
This is a part of "test.xml"

```
<![CDATA[<b>]]>
```

If I show it in a browser, the browser shows it correctly:

```
<![CDATA[ <b> ]]>
```

But when I read and show XML with XStream I see only:

```
<b>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken each element should have a name and a value, (if their being read in as Xppdom objects). I'm guessing what you're looking at is the value. with the  it might be a little different, because it is unparsed data, so the name may be "!CDATA" or may not have one at all. In the normal case: if you have `<node attr1='val1'> text </node>`, when it is read in, calling `.getName()` will return `"node"`, `.getValue()` will return `text`, and `.getAttribute("attr1")` will return `"val1"`.

If you wanted to print everything with their tags you could make a method `String formatXppDom(XppDom elem)` to format a printable string with the tags.